# ::before não funciona como deveria

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

Eu comprei um CSS e estou tentando aplicar no meu site, o cass que eu comprei tem uma esquema de validação no form onde ele circula o form com uma linha vermelha e coloca um X dentro da caixa de texto.
Vou colocar uma imagem aqui para ficar fácil de entende, essa é do template que eu comprei.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Agora, o meu fica dessa forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A diferença do HTML é a inclusão de um ::before e de uma classe (que eu acho q é ela que coloca o before, mas não sei bem como isso funciona, estou aprendendo)

O componente do form fica em um , segue o exemplo do primeiro componente já com a validação de erro ativa:

```html
<div class="form-group  has-error">
::before
<label class="sr-only" for="Nome">Nome</label>
                
<input class="input-validation-error form-control input-lg required text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="O campo Nome é obrigatório." id="name" name="Nome" placeholder="Name" type="text" value=""> <ul class="parsley-errors-list" id="parsley-id-1125"></ul>
                
                
</div>
```

O ::before é o "X" que eu quero colocar, ele tem o seguinte css:

```css
.contact-form .has-error:before {
    content: "\f00d";
    color: #d2322d;
}
```

Porque no meu projeto ele tem um quadrado e no projeto comprado é um X?

Comment: Esse tipo de coisa (`content: "\f00d";`) normalmente vem de arquivos de fonte. Você incluiu todas as fontes que vieram no template no seu projeto?

Comment: Verifique se no console você está recebendo algum erro. Poste também o seu BundleConfig do MVC.

Comment: O before está funcionando corretamente, o problema é a fonte. O before adiciona  conteúdo da sua div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O Font Awesome está instalado errado. Como é ASP.NET MVC, [utilize o pacote NuGet apropriado para usá-lo](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FontAwesome/).

Verifique também se no seu arquivo `App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` há uma entrada CSS para o CSS do Font Awesome. Eu uso assim:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/BundledContent/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  /* Aqui tem mais uma cacetada de coisas, mas vou pular pro que interessa */
                  "~/Content/font-awesome.css"));
```

Verifique também seu `web.config` para permitir algumas extensões em modo estático. A rota do ASP.NET MVC costuma interpretar errado essas referências:

```
<configuration>
...
  <system.webServer>
  ...
    <staticContent>
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".json" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="text/json" />
    </staticContent>
  ...
  </system.webServer>
...
</configuration>
```